# C++ in VS2010 running a managed C# DLL targeting .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, c++, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I have a C++ project, created in Visual Studio 2010, which needs to execute code from a C# DLL.  I have done so using the

```
#import "pathname\filename.tlb" raw_interfaces_only
```

directive, as well as the CoInitialize(NULL) and CoUninitialize() COM calls.

The C# DLL was compiled in VS2012, and targeted .NET 4.5.

I was able to compile and run the project, and it seemed as though everything was fine, but we were noticing differences in some function calls.  This was verified by loading the exact same C++ project into VS 2012, turning on /clr in Configuration Properties, and changing the Targeted Framework (of the C++ project) to v4.5 by modifying the .vcxproj file in Notepad.

So, I guess my questions are:

1. Why does a C++ project need to target a .NET framework?  Shouldn't the C# DLL be able to handle that by itself? (Answered by Hans Passant)
2. Why is it possible to run a C#.NET v4.5 DLL through C++ with /clr off, and not have any warnings that it might not work? (Answered by Hans Passant)
3. Why do I even get results back from the function call?  How is it possible that the C# DLL "works" (returns coherent results) at all?  Why does it return different values when targeting .NET v4.0?
4. Is it possible to use the C# DLL from the C++ code, while still using VS 2010?  Or do I need to switch the project to VS 2012?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

A native C++ project does not target the .NET Framework at all.  The project creation wizard is a bit clumsy, it does not hide the combobox when you create the C++ project.

What framework version the C# DLL needs is established when you register it.  Either done automatically when you tick the "Register for COM interop" build setting or explicitly by running Regasm.exe.

That native C++ code can call C# code without trouble is just a goody you get from using COM.  Whose basic purpose is to provide the contracts and the glue to allow one language to call code written in another.  The CLR has very good COM support and makes it look very easy.  That's not the case for C++, writing COM client code is generally unpleasant due to the verbosity and it is pretty easy to make mistakes.  Using `raw_interfaces_only` is a mistake, you don't get the benefit of memory management with smart pointers and error handling with exceptions.

Comment: I think you answered the first 2 questions, so thanks for that.  [This KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/828736) only mentions VS 2005, but I'd imagine it should also be applicable to more recent versions.  Why do you think it says to use raw_interfaces_only?  Modifying my code to remove that directive doesn't change the result at all (still works with CLR and targeting 4.5, still doesn't work without CLR and targeting 4.0).

Comment: Because when you use raw_interfaces_only, you are much too likely to skip on the *required* error checking.  C# code likes to throw exceptions, if you don't write the error checking code then you just don't know that something went wrong.  And can't know, all you got is "it doesn't work".  Not the kind of diagnostic you can ever get help with at SO.

Comment: I didn't even get "it doesn't work".  I got a valid (looking) result, and get that with or without `raw_interfaces_only`. The only reason I know it's wrong is because people testing entirely in C# have gotten different results.

Comment: Well, that narrows it down.  You'll have to avoid relying on psychic powers and ask a *specific* question about it.  Code snippet and results required.